# How to get the value of a column in a row in which the other column has maximal value?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, where-clause

I have a table with three fields `user_name`, `page` and `n_loads`. I would like to group the table by `user_name`, for each user name I would like to show maximal number of loads and the page that corresponds to this (maximal) number of loads. Can I do it in one MySQL clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  username, MAX(n_loads) n_loads
            FROM    tableName 
            GROUP   BY username
        ) b ON  a.username = b.username AND
                a.n_loads = b.n_loads
```

or

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   n_loads = 
        (SELECT MAX(b.n_loads)
        FROM    tableName b
        WHERE   a.username = b.username);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both query*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e3ba/3)

Comment: The answer needs a +1. Good answer..!!.. Window functions are a good alternative..but not supported on MySQL..!!